# Domain Route Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, dns

I have two domains: 
www.maindomain.com
www.teststore.com

In my main domain I have a URL as:
www.maindomain.com/my-store

And i can be dynamic as: my-store, other-store, more-store, etc.

But some stores has his own domain, so in the database I save his domain: teststore.com

in Laravel proyect I have the next code for: maindomain.com

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{store}', 'namespace' => 'Store'], function () {
      Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('store.home');
})
```

So, when i enter to maindomain.com/my-store I see the store content.. good!

Now I have a other domain (teststore.com) that is pointed to www.maindomain.com... If I enter to teststore.com/my-store works as maindomain.com.

Now I created a new group with domain:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'teststore.com'], function()
{
    dd('2');
});
```

When I enter to teststore.com I see a "2", BUT when I enter to maindomain.com I also see a "2".

Why?

Next question: How I can make routes for "teststore.com" and show the content of maindomain.com/my-store? put directly the "store" variable with the value "my-store" or something like that.

Thanks

Comment: Tell you the truth, i didn't understood the question.

Comment: I think the second Route is missing the method inside.